# SQL - How to join two tables that are based on a bit condition and will always populate the field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join two tables in MS SQL Server.
One table contains the persons Name and their ID.

```
+----+---------+--------------+---------+
| ID |  Name   |    phone     |  email  |
+----+---------+--------------+---------+
|  1 | John A. | 111-111-1111 | a@email |
|  2 | Sara B. | 111-111-1112 | b@email |
|  3 | Joe C.  | 111-111-1113 | c@email |
|  4 | Jane D. | 111-111-1114 | d@email |
+----+---------+--------------+---------+
```

The other table contains the ID, the languages they know, and a bit that indicates if it is their native language.

```
+----+----------+---------+
| ID | Language | Native  |
+----+----------+---------+
|  1 | English  | True    |
|  1 | Spanish  | False   |
|  2 | Spanish  | True    |
|  2 | English  | False   |
|  2 | French   | False   |
|  3 | French   | False   |
|  3 | Spanish  | False   |
|  4 | English  | True    |
+----+----------+---------+
```

The table I want should show the id, persons name, their native language or which ever language is returned first, if this is their native language, phone number, email.

```
+----+---------+----------+--------+--------------+---------+
| ID |  Name   | Language | Native |    phone     |  email  |
+----+---------+----------+--------+--------------+---------+
|  1 | John A. | English  | True   | 111-111-1111 | a@email |
|  2 | Sara B. | Spanish  | True   | 111-111-1112 | b@email |
|  3 | Joe C.  | French   | False  | 111-111-1113 | c@email |
|  4 | Jane D. | English  | True   | 111-111-1114 | d@email |
+----+---------+----------+--------+--------------+---------+
```

I have tried joining the tables and providing a where condition but it either returns only the native languages or all of the languages that the person knows.  I have also tried grouping by the ID, which said that the columns are invalid in the selected list.  I put all the columns into the group by clause but that gave me operand data type bit is invalid for max operator.

```
SELECT p.ID
      ,p.Name
      ,l.Language
      ,coalesce(max(l.native),0) as native
      ,p.phone
      ,p.email
  FROM people as p
  JOIN Languages as l on p.ID = l.ID
  group by p.id
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid, will return an unpredictable result in older MySQL versions, will raise an error in new versions (unless in compatibility mode.) The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: "Whichever is returned first" isn't a reasonable condition. Is there some other condition you can apply here like `max(language)` using lexicographical sort?

Comment: @JNevill a max(language) using lexicographical sort is fine as is having a NULL.  The condition for that column is the complex part that i can't get to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your RDBMS doesn't support window functions, then something like this should work:

```
SELECT p.ID
      ,p.Name
      ,COALESCE(l.Language, l2.language) as language
      ,coalesce(l.native, l2.native) as native
      ,p.phone
      ,p.email
  FROM people as p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Languages as l on p.ID = l.ID
    AND (l.native = 'true')
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id, max(Language), native FROM Languages WHERE native = 'false' GROUP BY id, native) as l2 on p.ID = l2.ID
    AND ()
  group by p.id
```

Comment: it is giving me an error `No column was specified for column 2 of l2`

Comment: If I remove the second outer join it is returning the results I need with the language containing a NULL value if the person doesn't have the native language set to true.  I am just interested in the full solution you provided.

Comment: Change that max(language) to `max(language) as language` and it should clear up. An alias is necessary for subqueries.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server solution:

```
create table person (
    id int,
    name varchar (45),
    phone varchar (45),
    email varchar (45)
    );
create table languages (
    id int,
    language varchar (45),
    Native bit
    );
insert into person values    
(1, 'John A.', '111-111-1111', 'a@email'),
(2, 'Sara B.', '111-111-1112', 'b@email'),
(3, 'Joe C.', '111-111-1113', 'c@email'),
(4, 'Jane D.', '111-111-1114', 'd@email');
insert into languages values
(1, 'English', 1 ),
(1, 'Spanish', 0),
(2, 'Spanish', 1 ),
(2, 'English', 0),
(2, 'French', 0),
(3, 'French', 0),
(3, 'Spanish', 0),
(4, 'English', 1 );

select t1.id, t1.name, t2.language, t2.native, t1.phone, t1.email
from person t1 inner join 
(select *, row_number () over (partition by id order by id) rn
 from languages) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
 where t2.rn =1
```

Results:

```
+----+---------+----------+--------+--------------+---------+
| id |  name   | language | native |    phone     |  email  |
+----+---------+----------+--------+--------------+---------+
|  1 | John A. | English  | True   | 111-111-1111 | a@email |
|  2 | Sara B. | Spanish  | True   | 111-111-1112 | b@email |
|  3 | Joe C.  | French   | False  | 111-111-1113 | c@email |
|  4 | Jane D. | English  | True   | 111-111-1114 | d@email |
+----+---------+----------+--------+--------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. You didn't say what DBMS you're using, so I'll assume MySQL as the most common open source product.

You can do it using a sub-query containing a LIMIT 1 clause (TOP 1 in SQL Server, but might not work in a subquery).

You should probably use an OUTER join in case some person has no language listed. The ORDER BY and LIMIT selects the native language or the first one alphabetically. Note there is no real "first" language, SQL has no record ordering, so you need to use ORDER BY to give a meaning to "first".

```
SELECT  p.ID,
        p.Name,
        p.phone,
        p.email,
        l.Language,
        l.Native
FROM    people as p,
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT ID, Language, Native
         FROM Languages
         ORDER BY CASE WHEN Native THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, Language
        LIMIT 1) as l
ON      p.ID = l.ID
```

I haven't tested this, but the approach is right. Let me know if it has a problem and I'll update the syntax.

Comment: @Ostreva: so which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Microsoft SQL Server.